# How do I host a NodeJS http web server on a raspberry PI/or any linux based PC

Tags: linux, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, httpserver

I've seen people host Apache servers on raspberry PI's and of course on regular computers. I do not wish to or rent a VPS and thought it would be best to set one up on my Raspberry PI 2 B:

```
(1gb ram/32gb disk/1ghz on overclock)
```

What is the proper way of setting up a NodeJS http web server on a computer? Can you link me to a tutorial if one exists(Couldn't find any).

I was also wondering if I would be better of renting a VPS with recurring costs and lack of customization/control , or on a working dedicated PC. Keep in mind that I wish to practice some dev ops work over multiple PI's(ex. Chef).

I need this server to be accessible through the internet through an ip or domain. How do I go about setting that up? (I have domains)

### *Update*: I wrote a blog post on this subject.

The tutorial goes through the full installation process. Click the link below

[image: Hosting a Node.js HTTP server on a Raspberry Pi]

Comment: Great blog post, I am thinking about buying a Pi for this exact purpose, this helps. Thanks!

Comment: The nodejs provided by apt-get is outdated, you better get the latest one from the official site https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ (arm armv6 for raspabrry pi 1 and armv7 for raspberry pi 2 or 3)

Comment: Answers do not belong in the question, so your "update" has been rolled back. If you'd like to answer your own question, you should do so. However, note that a YouTube video is not a sufficient answer---you need to summarize the relevant portions of the video so that your answer here is complete and self-contained. The link should only be as an additional reference.

Comment: This question needs to be closed cause it's far too broad and asks for third party tutorials which is not allowed on SO.

Comment: the link is't live

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use raspberry as your VPS or dedicated server. Just assign static IP address(*You need to buy*) to your Raspberry and then point your domain name to that static IP address.

Few links below that will be helpful for you,

- https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update
- https://in.godaddy.com/help/point-your-domain-name-to-a-server-19116